# Connected component and Tutte polynomial

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to find a Tutte polynomial for a graph. And i am confused with the definition of that as well as the definition of connected component.

[image]

From the definition above, does the notation $k(E)$ means the number of connected components of G?

and about the definition of the connected component, i have got the following definition from wiki that a connected component is a subgraph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by paths, and which is connected to no additional vertices in the supergraph. So according to this definition, is it make sense to say the complete graph $K_3$ has 2 connected component since $K_3$ itself have any two vertices connected; as well as another subgraph which by deleting one edge from $K_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the final line in the definition, $k(E)$ is the number of connected components of the graph $(V,E)$.  Since $G=(V,E)$, then $k(E)$ is the number of connected components of $G$.

The definition of a connected component in the first sentence of the Wikipedia article is somewhat confusing.  The "As an equivalence relation" section has perhaps a better definition: say a vertex is *reachable* from another if there is a path from that vertex to the other.  Reachability is an equivalence relation, and each equivalence class is called a *connected component*.

For example, since $K_n$ has a path from every vertex to every other, it has exactly one connected component.  A visual way to think about connected components is that when you draw it on paper you can separate each connected component from each other, like in the illustration on the Wikipedia article.

Something to watch out for in the definition of $k$ is that $k(A)$ is the number of connected components of $(V,A)$, and *not* the number of connected components of the graph induced by the edges $A$ (this caught me when I first learned about the Tutte polynomial).  For example, $k(\emptyset)=\lvert V\rvert$ since there are no paths from any vertex to any other, so each vertex is in its own connected component.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Do you mind to explain more about the bit ' A visual way to think about connected components is that when you draw it on paper you can separate each connected component from each other.'

Is it possible to explain how should i count it if i am dealing with a graph that not every vertex got a path to every other?

Comment: @Thomas Imagine making a graph by taking a small metal loop for each vertex and then attaching lengths of string to these loops, one piece of string per edge.  This is special string that never knots up and can pass through itself and other pieces of string completely freely.  Now, choose a vertex and and pull it away from the rest of the graph.  Everything that follows along with this vertex is part of the same connected component.  Once this subgraph has been drawn out of the rest of the graph, place it somewhere far away.  Repeat to get the rest of the connected components.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried to do the imagination and i realise if i link up the different vertex with loop and strings, the whole graph will be pulled away no matter which vertex. Does that mean the graph i drew got exactly one component or did i actually doing the wrong imagination?        Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it does not matter which vertex you choose to pick up.  If the whole graph pulls away, then it has exactly one connected component.